# tab not working when dynamically added using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, html-lists, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-append

i am using the existing jquery UI tabs..

```
 <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">title 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>t1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>t2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>t3 content</p>
    </div>
</div>    

when rendered in the browser, jquery adds some set of classes to the <li> elements. [some part of it given below]

<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
       <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
       <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
       <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
</ul>


when I append some <li> elements in <ul> using the following jquery code:

$('#tabs ul').append($('<li><a href="#tabs-4">title 4</a></li>');
```

The list gets appended but the classes are not added to it, hence do not exhibit the tab functionality.

Please give some insight into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add the div with the tab id:

```
    var num_tabs = $('div#tabs ul li.tab').length + 1;        
    $('div#tabs ul').append(
        '<li class="tab"><a href="#tab-' + num_tabs + '">Section ' + num_tabs + '</a></li>');

    $('div#tabs').append(
        '<div id="tab-' + num_tabs + '"></div>');
```

Then try a refresh on `tabs`:

```
 $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
```

[WORKING Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKBqy/61/)

Comment: Nope. Its not working out! Actally I have a button <button id="buttonId">Add Tab</button> ...and the following jquery function...$(document).on('click', '#buttonId', function () {            
        $('#tabs ul').append($('<li><a>add me</a></li>'));
        $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    });

Comment: Thank you!. it works. I used load() to append the tabs, but I failed to refresh them inside the callback method.

Comment: Brilliant! The "refresh" was what I was missing. Thanks @Italhouarne!

Comment: @AmiSchreiber my pleasure!